# Ruby decimal (8.0 + 63.27 = 71.27000000000001)

Tags: ruby, decimal

When doing the following in irb:
`8.0 + 63.27`
Yields the following result:
 `=> 71.27000000000001`

Does anyone have a clue what's up with that?

Better yet, does anyone have a clue how to correct this?

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

EDIT: Thanks for the articles about floating point calculations. I feel stupid for not knowing after programming for so many years.

(removed the bug tag)

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Comment: Or, if you have some extra time: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common issue (not a bug) when dealing with [floating point values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Use `BigDecimal` (available in standard library) in case you need accurate representation.

Answer (score 3):

For a laymans description of why you get this result, try [Why are floating point calculations so inaccurate?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm). For some real meaty detail, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

To mitigate these problems, use [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) as suggested in other answers or you could try using [Flt](http://flt.rubyforge.org/), an arbitrary precision floating point library for Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, this is due to the way floating point are internally represented. Internally floatings uses `base 2`. Due to this, a number that has a finite representation in ten base, can became periodic in base two. Converting back after some computation can show the behavior you refer. To solve such a situations avoid checking for equality floating point values, but compare them with a sensible epsilon.

Comment: Well sure, but it's incorrect, right? 8.0 + 63.27 = 71.27. Is there a way to get a proper calculation?

Comment: @JeffreyW Unfortunately it cannot be represented more accurate way when storing numbers as floats. Similar issue is also in Python: `0.2+0.1=0.30000000000000004`

Comment: Use BigDecimal as @plaes suggested.

Comment: Can you give me an accurate calculation of 2/3 in decimal?  Of course not!  But you can do it in base 3 just fine: 0.2.  What you're seeing is the roundoff error that is equivalent to the 7 in 0.6666666666666667.  It's a fact of life in representing numbers in approximate ways.  You can always print your numbers out to a lesser precision, which would give you what you're expecting.

Comment: @JeffreyW. try with a paper to divide 10/3, and then multiply by 3 again, do you obtain 10 back?

Comment: @FelicePollano Actually you do get the same number. 10 and 9.999... are just two different representations of the same number (1 = 9/9 = 0.999...).

Comment: @maenu yes it is exactrly what i tryed to explain to the OP